# Compare all entries of an attribute in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

In short, I want to write a query that is similar to a "while" loop in other programming languages like Java, C, Python, and such...

What I found is something like a bounded for loop
I have a Flight entity which has an airline attribute, I want to check which airline has the most flights, is there any way this can be done in Oracle DBMS?

Update: to explain more
I have the entity FLIGHT(FNumber, Airline)
so for example Fnumber is 300 and Airline is "Delta Airlines"
I have a lot of these entries and want to check which airline has the most flights, this can be done by counting different flight numbers of the same airline as pno is a primary key, but I have no idea how to proceed further

Comment: Loops are rare in SQL.  There may be other ways to do what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff any idea how?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your required output derived from that data.

Comment: Did you try using a select query, could you send you your table structure ,sample data and output of what you want , may be a select with group by could give you what you want.

Comment: I just explained more @APC

Comment: @hkandpal haven't tried that, just updated my question for further clarification

Comment: @Sergio . . . Ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Comment: Your question illustrates a very important point about learning SQL. Don't start with learning the language. Start with understanding the **concepts** - they are significantly different from the concepts of an imperative language like C. In a sense, trying to write loops manually in a SQL statement is similar to trying to write assembly code for a loop when you program in C. Start by reading about the fundamental ideas and philosophy of **declarative** programming languages (such as SQL). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop is almost always the wrong approach in SQL. Ideally you want one statement which processes all the rows.

In this case, it sounds like you're trying to do something like:

- For a given flight number ( `where flight_number = :fno` )
- Count how many rows there are for each airline ( `group by airline` )
- Return the airline with most rows ( `order by count(*) desc fetch first 1 rows only` )

Which you can do with:

```
select airline
from   flights
where  flight_number = 300
group  by airline
order  by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong, I want to count which airline has the most flights, this can be done by counting different flight numbers of the same airline as pno is a primary key, no idea how to do it since it is for all airlines and not a fixed amount of flights.

Comment: Then remove the where clause - this will show which across all flights, which airline has the most rows (flights)

Comment: May I ask you what the last line is for?

Comment: To stop returning data after getting N rows. So this returns whichever airline has the highest count (number of rows) in the table

Comment: This resulted in "SQL statement not properly ended"

Comment: @Sergio - Are you using a particularly old version of Oracle?

Comment: @JustinCave I am using version 11

Comment: `fetch first` was added in 12c, in 11g and earlier you'll need to use the [rownum trick](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results)